# Angular routing - need an observable which triggers at every url change

Tags: angular

I need an observable stream which triggers when the url of my app changes. In particular, I need this for when the url initially changes from `"/"` to the actual first route (e.g. `"/home"`).

I tried using

```
this.router.events.pipe(
      filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationStart)
)
```

but this doesn't work (i.e. it doesn't trigger for this initial change of route; I believe it may be because it only triggers when the route is changed as a result of the user's interaction with the app).

Is there a work around?

Comment: where did you put this listener? did you put that in `app.component.ts`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not a function in router-outlet?

```html
<!-- app.component.ts -->
<router-outlet (activate)="onActivate($event)"></router-outlet>
```

in app component:

```js
onActivate(event) {
  window.scroll(0, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you asked for but you can subscribe to the router and listen for the change from there

```
class MyClass {
  constructor(private router: Router) {
    router.events.subscribe((val) => {
        // see also 
        console.log(val instanceof NavigationEnd) 
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I tried and didn't work as I mentioned in my post!